# Validar explode

Tags: php

**Código**:

```
$pessoa = "CARLOS";

$nome = explode ( " ", $pessoa, 2)[0];

$sobreNome = explode ( " ", $pessoa, 2 )[1] == null 
             ? "VAZIO" 
             : "sobreNome: " . explode ( " ", $pessoa, 2 )[1] ;

print "Nome: " . $nome . "<br />";
print "sobreNome: " . $sobreNome;
```

**Objetivo**:

Se ***explode ( " ", $pessoa, 2 )[1]*** não for possível poque a pessoa só cadastrar apenas 1 nome, sobrenome fica com o termo **VAZIO**

Como fazer?

**Obs.:** Da forma que fiz dá o seguinte erro.

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in D:\Trabalhos\host\htdocs\hotplateprensas.com.br\teste.php on line 9
Nome: CARLOS
VAZIO
```

**Em tempo**:

Caso eu faça:

```
$pessoa = "CARLOS ALBERTO";
```

*Então não dá erro.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se o nome completo da pessoa não possuir um espaço em branco, a função `explode` irá retornar um *array* de apenas um elemento no índice zero; você não pode acessar o índice 1 assumindo que ele existirá, pois quando não existir dará o erro citado.

Além disso, você chamou a função `explode` 3 vezes para a mesma *string* em 2 linhas de código basicamente; isso é um claro sinal que você deve refatorá-lo.

```
$nomeCompleto = "Carlos";

$nomes = explode(" ", $nomeCompleto, 2);

$nome = array_shift($nomes);
$sobrenome = array_shift($nomes) ?? "Vazio";
```

Assim, `$nomes` será o *array* retornado por `explode`; a função `array_shift` irá remover o primeiro elemento retornando-o para `$nome`. Se não houver o sobrenome, a função `array_shift` irá retornar `NULL` e através do operador de coalescência nula é atribuído o valor `"Vazio"` quando isso ocorrer.

Mas você pode simplificar ainda para:

```
$nome = $nomes[0];
$sobrenome = $nomes[1] ?? "Vazio";
```

Pois o operador de coalescência nula intrinsecamente verificará se o índice 1 existe no *array* antes de retorná-lo.

Comment: vou aceitar sua resposta mas gostaria de uma orientação. O que você acha dessa abordagem? $sobreNome = ! isset ( explode ( " ", $pessoa, 2 )[1] )
     ? "VAZIO" 
    : explode ( " ", $pessoa, 2 )[1] ;

Comment: @CarlosRocha Desnecessária. Por que executar a mesma função 2x?